# Handling a user tapping on a Siri IntentsUI to go to the correct view in app when the app is terminated / NOT in the background

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, siri

I have a Siri Intent that displays the following UI.

[[image]]

When the user taps on it, the app is launched.

When the app *is in the background*, I use the following code in the Scene Delegate to capture what the user did and take the user to the right view. It works as expected.

```
        func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
            print("CONTINUE USER ACTIVITY")
            guard let intent = userActivity.interaction?.intent as? WasteWizardIntent else {
                print("AppDelegate: WasteWizardIntent - FALSE")
                //return false
                return
            }
            print("AppDelegate: WasteWizardIntent - TRUE")
            print(intent)
            appState.selectedTab = .wastewizard
            appState.deepLinkActionSheet = true
            appState.deepLinkString = intent.garbage!
            //contentView.wasteWizard.viewModel.goToWasteItem(for: intent.garbage!)

        }
```

However, I can't figure out what to do when the app is launched when it is NOT in the background.

I've tried the following:

- In the SceneDelegate `scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)` method. When I put a breakpoint, the userActvity, intent and handoffUserActivityType are all nil.

```
            if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
                let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
                window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)

                RootAlerter.shared.rootViewController = window.rootViewController


                self.window = window
                window.makeKeyAndVisible()
                let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities
                let string = connectionOptions.handoffUserActivityType
                let intent = userActivity?.interaction?.intent as? WasteWizardIntent
                print("handoff type \(connectionOptions.handoffUserActivityType)")
        }
```

I also tried the following  methods but they never get called:

```
        func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) 
        func scene(_ scene: UIScene, didUpdate userActivity: NSUserActivity)
        func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String)
```

Also tried this in the AppDelegate

```
    private func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool
```

Comment: `UIScene.ConnectionOptions` must be filled as documented, if it is not - it is definitely a bug, submit feedback to Apple.